# Angular validate input type="email" as type="text"

Tags: javascript, validation, angularjs

My Angular app has a login form with an email/username input field:

```
<input type="email" required/>
```

Input is type="email" so the [correct keyboard is displayed in iOS](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1721-Default-To-The-Numeric-Email-And-URL-Keyboards-On-The-iPhone.htm).
However validation should be that of a type="text" input to allow for a username.

Basically I need override Angular to **validate type="email" as type="text"**
Here is a [basic Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/qtnfDOvWpVdMByK68Db3?p=preview) to get started.

**Note**: I've tried using ng-pattern to validate on regex but it only seems to work for type="text"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to change how input type='email' is handled in angular without changing it's source, but maybe instead you could try to:

```
<input type="text" required late-email />
```

```js
angular.module('yourApp').directive('lateEmail', function () {
    return {
        priority: -1,
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            elem.attr('type', 'email');
        }
    };
});
```

Important thing here is priority, as angularjs input directive needs to run(link) first so will use 'text' as input type, then lateEmail will change input type to email.

Comment: Forked the Plunk with Codefather's solution. I don't have my iPhone to hand right now but looking at inspector I assume it will work - http://plnkr.co/edit/GAlhFQlMhGNHeSs2TKrJ?p=preview

Comment: Tested on iPad and it works a treat. Thanks Codefather, marking as correct.